# useEffect infinite loop network request

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect, use-state, use-context

I am getting infinite requests on my network, and it's due to my useEffect. I know that the problem is because I am putting in the brackets as the second argument the 'posts' and the 'setPost' inside the useEffect function, but I need the page to render whenever I add a new post, so the 'posts' must be inside the brackets.

```
    function Home() {
const {userData, setUserData} = useContext(userContext)
const [posts, setPost] = useState([])
const [createPost, setCreatePost] = useState('')
const handleToken = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth-token')
}

const token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");

const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/posts', {textOfThePost: createPost}, {
        headers: { 'auth-token': token },
    })
    .then((res) => {setCreatePost("")})
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts')
    .then(res => {
        setPost(res.data)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
}, [posts])
```

Comment: you want to re-render when you add a new post?

Comment: You don't need to use useEffect here. You can just update the state.

Comment: @malong11 yes! just like twitter

Comment: @RunSmeagolRun what do you mean? All the post should appear as soon as the page load, that's why I'm using useEffect

Comment: @RunSmeagolRun is right you dont need useState here. just make a get request after you add a new post and update the state it should re-render itself since the state is updated

Comment: @gonzalovc15 as explained in above comment :)

Comment: its not working, im putting the get request in the function and leaving useEffect empty with just the [posts] as the second argument, but if I refresh the page  the posts doesn't appear until I create a new post

Comment: can you update the post with your current solution?

Comment: If you really want to show new entries in your database you need to consider something similar to a snapshot listener. Basically a function that will be triggered (in the frontend) by your database with the updated values. Take firestore real time updates as an example https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: How would the `posts` array get updated when someone else (on a different device, different state etc) is adding a post.

Comment: @RunSmeagolRun there i updated

Comment: When you update the post state, do it like this `setPost([ ...post, res.data ])`

Comment: that doesn't make the post appear when I load the page, still have to execute the function to them appear

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing `setPost` inside useEffect, I assume `posts` being changed, and you've added `posts` as dependency in `useEffect`, Of course which will re-call and it goes infinite loop. Make sure when do you want to call `posts` API.

```
const [posts, setPost] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts')
   .then(res => {
     setPost(res.data) // Which will change `posts`
   })
}, [posts]) // this will trigger useEffect and It goes infinite loop
```

```
// Change it to
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts')
   .then(res => {
     setPost(res.data) // Which will change `posts`
   })
}, []) -> Which call only one time
```

Comment: I said that that won't be a solution for me cause I need to update the page when a new post is created, and leaving the brackets empty avoid that to happen

Comment: you've just changed your question!, you didn't ask for this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This useEffects gets called everytime `posts` changes, and inside the useEffect you're changing posts value, so you got into an recursive loop.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts')
        .then(res => {
            setPost(res.data)
        })
    }, [posts])
```

If you want it to get called only once, you should leave the empty array in your effect, so it will only get called once when your component is mounted.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts')
        .then(res => {
            setPost(res.data)
        })
    }, [])
```

Comment: I said that that won't be a solution for me cause I need to update the page when a new post is created, and leaving the brackets empty avoid that to happen